# Nginx install on Mac OS X Lion. Cannot find PCRE

Tags: nginx, osx-lion, pcre

First up, I am trying to compile everything form source, I'm not using MacPorts or HomeBrew.

I have already installed pcre to `/usr/local/pcre-8.21` and symlinked this to `/usr/local/pcre`.

I have set `/usr/local/pcre/bin` to my `PATH` variable here.

```
`/usr/local:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/pcre/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`
```

I am now trying to install Nginx, but I keep getting this message:

`./configure: error: the HTTP rewrite module requires the PCRE library.
You can either disable the module by using --without-http_rewrite_module
option, or install the PCRE library into the system, or build the PCRE library
statically from the source with nginx by using --with-pcre=<path> option.`

I tried setting `--with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre/bin` but it just tries to re-install PCRE.

Can anyone help me get round this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre (BTW this is why people use macports/Homebrew to avoid this chasing of issues)

Comment: If I add a path for PCRE it will create a Makefile, but when you run make It throws an error as it tries to look for the pcre makefile. (On Linux I am all for package managers, but on the Mac I find them messy and unreliable. But yes they make life easier)

Comment: Sounds like pcre is not installed correctly where are its include and lib files?

Comment: all files and directories are installed under `/usr/local/pcre-8.21`. `/usr/local/pcre` is a symlink of this directory.

Comment: If it helps, these are the specific errors it throws when running configure: `checking for PCRE library ... not found
checking for PCRE library in /usr/local/ ... not found
checking for PCRE library in /usr/include/pcre/ ... not found
checking for PCRE library in /usr/pkg/ ... not found
checking for PCRE library in /opt/local/ ... not found`

Comment: OK, after playing with this a bit I managed to get it working.

I removed the install of PCRE and removed references to it from PATH. When running configure for nginx I set `--with-pcre=/usr/local/src/pcre-8.21` (The location of the PCRE Makefile).

I believe this compiles PCRE into Nginx (I maybe wrong), and it built and installed OK.

Answer (score 14):

Nginx requires PCRE – Perl Compatible Regular Expressions(http://www.pcre.org/)

download PCRE and install PCRE:

```
cd pcre-8.01
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

in nginx folder type in to install:

```
cd nginx-0.8.33
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-http_ssl_module
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer may already be found, but I still want to add my answer.
When you use    ./configure you should use --with-pcre=/path/to/pcre/source. So let's say the source code was saved in /usr/local/src/pcre then the command will look like this:

```
./configure --with-pcre=/usr/local/src/pcre
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Yeah, that was added in the question. In the end I think I removed my installation of PCRE and allowed it to re-install it whilst installing Nginx

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. These commands solved my problem:

Open MAC terminal and run this command:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null`

then Run:

`brew install pcre`

Done!

Source: http://macappstore.org/pcre-2/